# Is there a way to disallow dependencies on certain artifacts in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a problem with the maven artifact for junit.  It comes packaged with hamcrest, but I like to use a later version of hamcrest, so my projects need to use junit-dep and exclude the hamcrest dependencies.

I have a parent pom.xml with a dependencyManagement section to handle the version of junit-dep that I want and ensure that hamcrest is excluded.  However, I'm constantly running into an issue where some other test library includes a transitive dependency to junit.

Note that it's not the version number that's a problem.  It is the particular artifact.  I don't want junit, I want junit-dep.  Is there any way to say in my dependencyManagement (or anywhere else) that I *never* want to include junit of any version at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no **global exclude** option in dependency management.

On the other hand, if you don't want JUnit jar do be included ever, you may play the same trick as `commons-logging-99.0-does-not-exist.jar`.

Here is the link that describes the trick -> http://day-to-day-stuff.blogspot.com/2007/10/announcement-version-99-does-not-exist.html

Personally, I've found out that it's easier to do the job by using `<exclusions>` tag.

Comment: Too bad.  I am using exclusions which keeps it from getting introduced as a transitive dependency on jars that I already know about, but I find others on my team discover it anew (or worse, just leave the default junit 3.8.1 dependency in new pom.xml).

Comment: @jhericks. I highly suggest to create a parent super POM with a large `<dependencyManagement>` section, where all the dependency issues ironed out and make all you project inherit from that POM.  If you do this, in your `<dependency>` section you should only list version-less dependencies.  That way you know that all your dependencies has been accounted for in one central place.  If, by mistake, you will list a version-less dependency not in parent super POM, the maven will catch it and complain.